# Convert string to json does not work with json.dumps command

Tags: python, json

I need to convert a given string obtained as a result of a command to JSON document to access its various attributes.

The following are the commands in my program.

```
file_data = fs.get_last_version(filename).read()
file_data1 =  json.dumps(file_data)
```

`json.dumps` throws me exception and I am unable to convert the following data to JSON.

Please help on how should I convert to JSON

The output I have for the string is something like the following:

> \xd0\xdd\x8f\x13\xe8\x87+\a|\x10V]YP\xd2\x06oc\xd3]\x06\xfdC
>   \xb4iA^\x80\x15\x97o\x84\xfaD\xe0\xda`uz\x10\xbd[\xe7\xdd
>   \x98\xb7\x80\x90\xd1\x8c\xb6n4\x86\xfe#\xaci\x0e\x14\x82\xf5\x0fi\xdb|\xb8\xc2~0\xff\xca\xc3+\xbd\xc0\xdb\xd9\xea\xbf\xc0x!\x884\x1b\x14\xf0\xa2\xa5\xb5`\\xaa\x11\xd6\xb1\\x86\xdf\xad\x07\x9b\xd0\x87A\xff\x12\xc4{3m\xb8\xd1\xbb\xeb\x9a\xa5\xc1\x12rw\xdfc>m\xfb\xa6\x1d\x08\xe3\x91
>   \xa52$
>   \x8a\xa6\x1e_\xaa\x99O\x81\xb4d\xfb\r\x12\xf2dl\xaf\xed\xdfj\x1c\x18`{\x99\x1f\xc5\xc1\xfc`9\xfe\xc0\x8b\x95\xe0\x8d\xf7\x13\x9a\xf1\xfa\xe4\xa4\xabw\xc3\xfa\x99
>   \x1b\xc3~U\x0c\xbdR\xed\x85$xK1\xc7\xba"\xb4\xcd}\xb1\x040\xf5\xf3\xc1$\xf9\x8bS\xdb\xe2\xc0\x8a\x8f\x05G\xad!\xae\xa0\xb3=|\x1e\xac4*$\xfd\x08\xac(#;\x8f\xf9\xa1\xbaJ\xc8$\x05\xfd=\x7f9Z\xad\xc1\xe4\x10\xd6#\x9a\xa9\xbf?M\xda!\x937|\x12\xe2Z6\xbd\xb38~\x94W\x89\xe8t\x80\xf7\x8e\x08\xb6&\x80U\xec\xd7\x06`>\xe8K\xfdd\x8e\x02\xab\xc6\x19_\x88\x00\x1b\x84qTt\x82w\x12./\xe6\x81\xf7E\x90\xf0y\x1ai\xa7\xec*|>I\xd8\xf7\x9b\xee\x1b\xcc\xaf\xa4\x9d\xaa\x07$1_\xa8\x9fg\'\xed|\xf2\xccx5\xf8\xa0\xc6bw9\xc4\xd573\xed:\x06>\xb4y\xe87\x8e7\xf5\xc9P=4\xf5\xf3\xf4\xa4]\x8e\xc1L\x9f\xc1G-3s\xb0}vM\xcem\xcb\x02\x9bo\\\x83\x9f\xf7!i>\xdb\xde\xe7\x0f\xb6Z;\xd3\x8a\xf9\xb6\xfb\x81\xddk\xcc\x1f\x1b\xe6\x01\xb3V\xf0\x1e\'k_\xa8\x97\xb4\xcf\xff\x93tV[r\xc1x&\xd8\xb4\xd7O\xb3C|\xef\xf2\x14mlo\xdb\xd4\xdc\xabM`]^\xe3!:\xb0\xbd\xf3m\x87vt\x94\xd1ul\xef\x93%BBx\xbdz\xc9l\xbb\x9c\xc0N\xd6\xd57p\xfc\xea\xcb5\x89\x95\x82\x9d\xf7\x9e\xcd\x0fC\x0f<\xac\x86\xf1Jp~ysC)\xd8\x88\xed\xb3K\x0e\xd8\xd5X\x9e\x17\xdb\xcb\xe8m\xce\x16%\xb4\x1b[\xa2-\xf8\x90\x8ci
>   \xde\x1f\xcd\xa6/Z\xe8a\xfe!\xb88\xfb\x89b}9\x92\xd10a\x04\xa6\x1d\xdfL%\xa4\x1b\xc7\x83S\xc5n\x196\x88\x1fU\x99\xad\x19D\xa7\x9e\xbe\x81\xf9o~\x7f\x0bc\xfc\x12[l\xdeT\x0b\xf5\x87\xe0\xd4%\x90\xaf\x06q\x8b\xde\r\xc70_\x9c3\xe9dd\xc1\x96\xc5\xc3\x82x\xbd\xa7\xa7\xf9\xd7\xcb\x81\xad#\x92\x8a\x8b\xc0\xde

Comment: That's not an array or dict, so how exactly do you expect to convert it to JSON?

Comment: My objective is to convert the data I get to json to be used to get various tags available in it using mongo db commands. I am not sure of what is the data that is displayed.

Comment: That's a pile of unicode encoded data. Is that what the file looks like natively if you open it in a text editor?

Comment: @Geethanjali seeing how you're mentioning mongodb, this might be [`bson`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/) rather than `json`